# Runtime error 1004 : paste method of worksheet class failed after Screenshot

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, screenshot

I am trying to screenshot certain application and paste to excel sheet by using **AppActivate** and **Sendkeys 1068**, however sometimes, I receive a 1004 error on **Activesheet.Paste**,

"Paste method of Worksheet class failed".

Sometimes the macro works. I cannot pinpoint why this happens.

Can anyone identify issues with the code? Clearing the clipboard with **Application.CutCopyMode = False** works sometimes, but not always.

```
Sub testscreenshotplusemail()

Dim r As Range
Dim outMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim wordDoc As Word.Document
Dim count As Integer

AppActivate ("TESTING")

Application.CutCopyMode = False

Application.SendKeys "(%{1068})"

DoEvents

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))

Range("A5").Select

ActiveSheet.Paste

For Each pic In ActiveSheet.Pictures
count = count + 1
Next pic

If count = 0 Then
Exit Sub
End If

Set r = Range("A12:F37")
r.Copy

Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set outMail = outlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

SelectionBehalf = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F3").Value
SelectionTO = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G3").Value
SelectionCC = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H3").Value
SelectionSubj = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I3").Value
SelectionBody = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("F2").Value

With outMail
.SentOnBehalfOfName = SelectionBehalf
.Display
.To = SelectionTO
.CC = SelectionCC
.Subject = SelectionSubj
.Body = SelectionBody

Set wordDoc = outMail.GetInspector.WordEditor

wordDoc.Range(Start:=wordDoc.Range.End - 1).PasteAndFormat wdChartPicture


End With

For Each pic In ActiveSheet.Pictures
pic.Delete
Next pic
Application.SendKeys "{NUMLOCK}"
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: `Sendkeys` is unreliable and causes a lot of ambiguos problems. So, IMO, you will get some erratic behaviour with Sendkeys most of the times. If you really need to send keystrokes to an application you are better off with `keybd_event` ([reading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-keybd_event)). But this is more difficult to code.

Answer (score 0):

Using `SendKeys` is a reliable way of programming. Use Windows API functions instead of relying on keyboard commands where other software or applications may prevent from successfully running the code. See [How to do a screen capture using VBA](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/PrtSc.htm) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  In my case, it was caused because the user had the Windows Accessibility setting  "Use the Print screen key to open Snipping Tool" enabled.  So the paste command was attempted in the code before the user could do any snipping so it was trying to paste a blank.

Hope this helps.

I posted this morning a separate question about how to bypass/disable this Snipping Tool setting, but no answer yet.

Comment: Sorry, should have added: so try disabling the Windows setting